# show popup at the middle of screen using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have jsp page which shows some of the content based on some business logic.

What I want to achieve:

1. Show a popup/alert/messagebox in the middle of screen (on all sort of devices laptop/mobile/tab) after the entire page is loaded. That should grey-out entire background screen.
2. Popup should have close or "X" button to close.
3. Popup is sequence of 4-5 screens/content messages. Meaning as soon as popup comes it shows 1st content, then there should be "next" or ">" sort of icon within that popup screen. clicking on that it should proceed to next screen or content. When you arrive at last content or screen, you should be able to scroll back to first message.

I am not sure which language or combination of language I should use to achieve this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you search google? maybe https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Wizard-Modal-Bootstrap-jQuery/

Comment: Your question is not a simple coding question, it involves an entire script for a plugin. I don't know what kind of CMS your are dealing with, but if it's i.e. wordpress, just look for a plugin. This platform is for coding challenges, not how to code a plugin.

Comment: I am not using wordpress. Its simple JSP page written using HTML and javasript with either static content. May be in future I can use crafter to pull content to be displayed in popup.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks for the link. I will check the source code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp)

```js
$(".open").click(function() {
  if ($('#first_one').is(':visible')) {
    document.getElementById('prev').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'inline';

  }
});

$("#next").click(function() {
  var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next('p');
  $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:first").show();
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().prev('p');
  $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:last").show();
});


$("#next").click(function() {
  if ($('#fourth_one').is(':visible')) {
    document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'none';
  }
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  if ($('#first_one').is(':visible')) {
    document.getElementById('prev').style.display = 'none';
  }

  if ($('#third_one').is(':visible')) {
    document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'inline';
  }
});

$("#next").click(function() {
  document.getElementById('prev').style.display = 'inline';
});


var divClone = $(".text").clone();

$(".open").click(function() {
  $(".text").replaceWith(divClone.clone());
  $('.text').not(":first-child").hide();
});

$(".close").click(function() {
  $(".text").replaceWith(divClone);
});
```

```css
.open {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: 10px 6px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  z-index: 3;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  width: 600px
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.close:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="open">Open Modal</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close">&times;</span>
      <span>Welcome to the modal</span>
      <p class="text" id="first_one">Content 1</p>
      <p class="text" id="second_one" style="display:none">Content 2</p>
      <p class="text" id="third_one" style="display:none">Content 3</p>
      <p class="text" id="fourth_one" style="display:none">Content 4</p>
      <button id="prev">Prev</button>
      <button id="next">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this solution. However, it doesn't load modal after entire page load and it doesn't show it at the center of screen.

Comment: I tweaked some part of this snippet and it worked fine. I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Make your pop up in html, place it into a centered div with id and display it with javascript after document loaded, take a look here, it should work but i didn't tested it, so there can be something to adjust

css

```
#pop_up
{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   display: none;
   .....
}
#pop_up_close
{
   position:absolute;
   top:10px;
   right:10px;
   .....
}
```

html

```
<div id="pop_up">
   <div id="pop_up_close">...img or something else....</div>
   your pop up
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     $('#pop_up').css('display','block');

     $( "#pop_up_close" ).click(function() {
        $('#pop_up').css('display','none');
     });
});
```

Comment: for the slider you can use bootstrap carousel
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: I have tried above mentioned approach and I can't see any popup coming up. I also went thru carousel link but not sure how to run caousel inside popup alert. Any further ideas?

Comment: This helped partly.  I will post the answer soon.